# ActiveWorkbook.Save not working in Excel 2013 (prompting for overwrite)

Tags: vba, excel

I have problem with macro when running in Excel 2013 (macro was written in Excel 2010).
I am merging few files into one file. That file is saved with new file name (activeworkbook.saveas ...) .
After updating that final file (filtering, removing duplicates, etc.) when I use activeworkbook.save Excel 2013 is prompting for overwrite file. Even I allow overwrite, file is not saved. This problem occurred only when running under Excel 2013.
Any idea why activeworkbook.save is not working properly?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you make a MCVE question and giving as less code as needed to replicate - https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Did you use `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` before saving the file?

Comment: `Activeworkbook` is probably not pointing at the workbook you're expecting, and it's saving the wrong file. Reference the workbook directly without using `Activeworkbook`, perhaps using `Set` at the start to tidy up the code.

Comment: @sktneer: No, I'm trying to avoid disabling displayalerts unless it's really necessary.

Comment: @CLR: Bingo!!!! Thank you very much. As I was using Excel 2010 I expected that activeworkbook will be the workbook that was active right before workbook that I just closed.

Comment: @CLR if you place you comment as the answer, the thread will show as answered.

Answer (score 0):

`Activeworkbook` is probably not pointing at the workbook you're expecting, and it's saving the wrong file. Reference the workbook directly without using `Activeworkbook`, perhaps using `Set` at the start to tidy up the code.